# Eclipse from remote files/folders on amazon server

Tags: eclipse, remote-access

I have a VM from amazon. On that VM I have eclipse installed in which a web application is configured. Currently I am working in this way

```
1) Login to my VM
2) Open Eclipse
3) Run the server
4) Edit/Update code (that is very slow via Remote Desktop)
```

I want to edit/update code from my machine and when clicking save it should update my code that that eclipse which is on VM.

Is it possible? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon your question.
If you didn't find it already, what you are looking for is the [RSE plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/).
Here is a detailled tutorial on how to [set it up for Amazon EC2](http://www.wong101.com/tech-cloud/how-setup-eclipse-remote-system-explorer-linux-ec2-instance).